Finding date intervals in dataframe with plausibilty for breaks or overlap in R
I am looking for a method to find a sum of date intervals where there might be date breaks or date overlap. Specifically, in this case, I want to know how long a person owned a car (sum of years), but they might have owned a two cars at a time (I don't want that to count double) or they might have had a break where they did not own a car.
Here is some example data:
person <- c("Layla", "Layla", "Layla", "John", "John", "John", "Bo", "Bo")
car <- c("Volvo x", "Volvo y", "Fiat Q", "Tesla C", "Mazda H", "Ford W", "Honda 1", 
"Honda 2")
from_date <- as.Date(c("2000-01-01", "2009-01-02", "2011-01-05", "2000-08-01", "2004-07-09", "2008-01-01", "2001-01-01", "2003-07-01"))
end_date <- as.Date(c("2010-01-01", "2012-07-01", "2015-08-09", "2002-01-01", "2020-10-22", "2010-01-01", "2020-08-09", "2019-10-01")

data <- data.frame(person, car, from_date, end_date)

Such that
   person     car     from_date   end_date
1  Layla      Volvo x 2000-01-01  2010-01-01
2  Layla      Volvo y 2009-01-02  2012-07-01
3  Layla      Fiat Q  2011-01-05  2015-01-01
4   John      Tesla C 2000-01-01  2002-01-01
5   John      Mazda H 2004-08-01  2020-10-22
6   John      Ford W  2008-01-01  2010-08-01
7     Bo      Honda 1 2001-01-01  2020-06-01
8     Bo      Honda 2 2003-07-01  2019-10-01

The result I want:
Person carowner_yearsum
Layla   15,0
John    8,0
Bo      19,5

PS: My problem is similar to this: overlapping intervals in a dataframe in r, but genomicrangers is not compatible with R 4.3.1

Just checking - excluding end year (end_date)  in you expected results is by design? And your are dealing with just year values, not actual dates?

Oh sorry - in reality, I deal with dates! I will update the question ASAP.

@SofieAbildgaard it's fine to edit but if you're thinking of making substantive changes after you have an answer please read this Meta thread on chameleon questions.

Thank you @SamR

@SofieAbildgaard I don't understand your new expected output. Layla has a car continuously from 2000-01-01 to 2015-08-09 so why is her carowner_yearsum == 15, 0? I thought you might rounding to nearest year but Bo has a value of 19,5. Can you explain?

Note that years are not a straightforward way to count date intervals. Not only not all years have the same duration (although you can do days/365.25 to get an approximate result), but in some cases (e.g. ages), you might want whole years, and then you need to use some logic to calculate the number of elapse birthdays.

@SofieAbildgaard I can see you have now changed the end date for Layla to 2015-01-01 in the printed output (though not the sample data) so that output makes sense. But why is John 18,0? Can you explain in words how you get to these results? Otherwise I would suggest reverting this question to the previous state where the current answers were correct, and asking a new question with a bit more detail.

@SamR again, my bad. Now it should be correct. I approciate your patience.

@SofieAbildgaard why is the output for John now 8,0? I assume that's a typo for 18,0? But I don't see why John should be 18,0 unless you're rounding to the nearest year, and then Bo wouldn't have the result 19,5...

I would expand the data ranges into long form then count the unique years per person.
Yearly data
This is with the data you originally posted with the dates as integer vectors of years, i.e.
data  <- structure(list(person = c("Layla", "Layla", "Layla", "John", "John", "John", "Bo", "Bo"), car = c("Volvo x", "Volvo y", "Fiat Q", "Tesla C", "Mazda H", "Ford W", "Honda 1", "Honda 2"), from_date = c(2000, 2009, 2011, 2000, 2004, 2008, 2001, 2003), end_date = c(2010, 2012, 2015, 2002, 2020, 2010, 2020, 2019)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

data.table approach
Brief but arguably a little terse.
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[,
    .(year = seq(from_date, end_date - 1)),
    .(person, car)
][,
    .(carowner_yearsum = uniqueN(year)),
    .(person)
]

#    person carowner_yearsum
#    <char>            <int>
# 1:  Layla               15
# 2:   John               18
# 3:     Bo               19

tidyverse approach
Alternatively, you can expand the data ranges using tidyr::uncount(). More verbose but arguably more expressive. A question of style and which packages you happen to be using.
library(dplyr)
data |>
    tidyr::uncount(
        end_date - from_date
    ) |>
    mutate(
        year = seq(unique(from_date), unique(end_date) - 1),
        .by = c(person, car)
    ) |>
    summarize(
        carowner_yearsum = n_distinct(year),
        .by = person
    )

#   person carowner_yearsum
# 1  Layla               15
# 2   John               18
# 3     Bo               19

Updated data with dates
In response to your update, I wouldn't use exactly the same approach as with yearly data. Expanding into yearly long form took your original data from 8 to 72 rows. The same approach with daily data wold create 26900 rows. This could get out of hand quickly. Instead, create a sequence by month and count the unique months. In this case this creates an intermediate table with 883 rows.
setDT(data)
data[, from_month := as.IDate(format(from_date, "%Y-%m-01"))]
data[, end_month := as.IDate(format(end_date, "%Y-%m-01"))]
data[
    ,
    .(month = seq(from_month, end_month - 1, by = "1 month")),
    .(person, car)
][
    ,
    .(
        carowner_yearsum = (n_months <- uniqueN(month)) %/% 12,
        carowner_monthsum = n_months %% 12
    ),
    .(person)
]
#    person carowner_yearsum carowner_monthsum
#    <char>            <num>             <num>
# 1:  Layla               15                 7
# 2:   John               17                 8
# 3:     Bo               19                 7

I have put the number of years and number of months in different columns as I can't bear to paste() numeric data into a character vector. This means you can sort by length of time by sorting by year and then months e.g. setorder(dat, carowner_yearsum, carowner_monthsum).

An approach similar to SamR's but without the need for data.table:
car_years <- function(x) {
  # Generate a sequence of years for each car
  seqs <- apply(x[, c("from_date", "end_date")], 1,
                \(y) y[1]:(y[2] - 1), simplify = F)
  # Get the number of unique years across all sequences
  length(unique(unlist(seqs)))
}
lapply(split(data, data$person), car_years)

$Bo
[1] 19

$John
[1] 18

$Layla
[1] 15

As noted on @margusl comment, it is arguable if the end year should be excluded or not.  If it is, if you are assuming that the sum of the partial parts of the start and end years are rounded to one year.  You'll be underestimating the ownership time for the cases when the car starts early in the acquisition year (e.g. February), and ends later than that on the final year (e.g. October).  Conversely, you'll be overestimating the ownership time when it starts late in the year, and ends earlier (e.g. Nov-2004 to Jan-2020). With a large number of cases these under- and over-estimations cancel out, and your average error will tend to zero.
If you don't want to assume this, and prefer to be less conservative with the year counts, then just remove the - 1 from the inline function inside the apply(), and you'll have the number of different calendar years in which that person had a car, regardless of how early or late on the year the ownership started or ended.
Update: using dates
The function above can easily be adapted into generating a sequence of days, instead of years:
car_days <- function(x) {
  seqs <- apply(x[, c("from_date", "end_date")], 1,
                \(y) seq.Date(as.Date(y[1]), as.Date(y[2]), by = "day"),
                simplify = F)
  length(unique(unlist(seqs)))
}

This will return the total days each person owned a car:
lapply(split(data, data$person), car_days)

$Bo
[1] 7161

$John
[1] 6469

$Layla
[1] 5700

As I noted in my comment to the question, converting days into years is not straightforward, and I leave that up to you.  The easiest way would probably be to divide the days by 365.25, assuming the error is negligible for the purpose of this analysis.

You can use inrange from data.table like below
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
data %>%
    reframe(
        carowner_yearsum = sum(inrange(
            seq(min(from_date), max(end_date), by = "year"),
            from_date,
            end_date
        )) - 1,
        .by = person
    )

such that
  person carowner_yearsum
1  Layla               15
2   John               18
3     Bo               19


or similarly counting based on days
data %>%
    reframe(
        carowner_daysum = sum(inrange(
            seq(min(from_date), max(end_date), by = "day"),
            from_date,
            end_date
        )),
        .by = person
    )

which gives
  person carowner_daysum
1  Layla            5700
2   John            6469
3     Bo            7161


Here's one with {lubridate} intervals, durations and periods + overengineered interval clustering with {igraph}.
Helper to group overlapping intervals:
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(igraph)

# cluster overlapping intervals with igraph
iv_clust <- function(intervals){
  # example intervals:
  # 2000-08-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 
  # 2004-07-09 UTC--2020-10-22 UTC 
  # 2008-01-01 UTC--2010-01-01 UTC
  
  # adjacency_matrix of interval overlaps
  m <- matrix(FALSE, ncol = length(intervals), nrow = length(intervals))
  
  # combinations to test for overlaps, also used as array indices
  m_idx <- combn(length(intervals), 2) |> t()
  #     [,1] [,2]
  # [1,]    1    2
  # [2,]    1    3
  # [3,]    2    3  

  # detect overlaps
  overlaps <- apply(m_idx, 1, \(x) int_overlaps(intervals[x[1]], intervals[x[2]]))
  # [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
  
  # mark overlap locations in m
  m[m_idx[overlaps,,drop = FALSE]] <- TRUE
  #       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
  # [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
  # [2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
  # [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  
  
  # cluster ids of connected graph components (overlaping intervals)
  g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m, mode = "max")
  # [1] 2--3
  components(g)$membership
  # [1] 1 2 2
}

Using it with dplyr:
data |> 
  # lubridate interval, iv_clust groups overlapping intervals within person group
  mutate(iv = interval(from_date, end_date),
         iv_clust = iv_clust(iv), .by = person) |> 
  group_by(person, iv_clust) |> 
  # union of overlapping intervals within person group (drops iv_clust group)
  summarise(clust_duration = purrr::reduce(iv, lubridate::union) |> as.duration()) |> 
  # duration sums by persons
  summarise(carowner_yearsum_dur = sum(clust_duration) |> as.duration()) |> 
  mutate(carowner_yearsum_per = as.period(carowner_yearsum_dur))

#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   person carowner_yearsum_dur      carowner_yearsum_per 
#>   <chr>  <Duration>                <Period>             
#> 1 Bo     618624000s (~19.6 years)  19y 0m 220d 6H 0M 0S 
#> 2 John   558748800s (~17.71 years) 17y 0m 257d 18H 0M 0S
#> 3 Layla  492393600s (~15.6 years)  15y 0m 220d 6H 0M 0S

Example data:
person <- c("Layla", "Layla", "Layla", "John", "John", "John", "Bo", "Bo")
car <- c("Volvo x", "Volvo y", "Fiat Q", "Tesla C", "Mazda H", "Ford W", "Honda 1", "Honda 2")
from_date <- as.Date(c("2000-01-01", "2009-01-02", "2011-01-05", "2000-08-01", "2004-07-09", "2008-01-01", "2001-01-01", "2003-07-01"))
end_date <- as.Date(c("2010-01-01", "2012-07-01", "2015-08-09", "2002-01-01", "2020-10-22", "2010-01-01", "2020-08-09", "2019-10-01"))

data <- data.frame(person, car, from_date, end_date)


this is an interesting solution by viewing the problem from a graph theory perspective, +1! And good to know the int_overlaps function from your answer!

Thanks, though have to say the idea of approaching overlapping objects through graph theory was something I picked from a recent question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/79020159/646761 .  I was just looking for opportunities to apply  it on different problems.
